# Is it possible to call a javafx application within a jbpm work item handler?

Tags: javafx, jbpm

I have never seen this be done. I have gone through the steps to mavenise the project also using the javafx maven plugin. (mvn clean jfx:jar)
I basically wanted to have the (domain specific task / work item handler) open a simple webview after taking say like two inputs to configure the url to be used, since I want it to point to a simple html of jasper reports for when I accept/reject a customer.

First Error:

`Process Instances failed to start: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:javafx.application.Application from [Module "deployment.business-central.war:main" from Service Module Loader]`

Console Log:

`21:31:14,903 ERROR [org.jboss.as.txn] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4) JBAS010152: APPLICA
TION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0`

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks Izzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have access to the javafx.application.Application class in your project.  Either add it to the business central WEB-INF/lib folder, or add it as a dependency of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jBoss so I don't know if this is useful to you. I have an internal server (not JavaFX) and I need to bring up a javaFX menu within the same JVM. This is what I did:

I created a new thread that extends Application:

```
public class TyInternalTestThread extends Application
          implements Runnable {
```

The run method starts the javaFX menu:

```
Application.launch(TyMenu.class, new String[0]);
```

The initiating class does:

```
TyInternalTestThread it = new TyInternalTestThread();
Thread newThread = new Thread(it, "TyInternalTestThread");  
newThread.start();
```

It works fine. If you cannot do this in jBoss, then perhaps the above will point you in a good direction.